# Usage of 'Those' who/'Those students who'/'students who'

Tags: grammar, grammar-myths

I have question related to grammar. Can I change the phrase ***"those who"*** With ***"Those students who"*** and **"Students who"** In the following context?

Here is the example:

1-Dear students, On 26 th December, Tuesday We have arranged a blood donation camp on the campus . ***Those who*** are intersted in donating blood may please contact John Dayal, the principal of Xyz college.

I think the phrase **'those who'** can be replaced with **"those students who"** and **"students who"**. If I replace it, will that be grammatical? Can any native speaker please answer this?

Comment: Actually, your question has nothing to do with **who**. You want to talk about the differences between **those**, **those students**, and **students**.

Comment: @LucianSava That's correct. That's what I wanted to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"**Those**" simply stands in place of a particular noun. You can surely use "**those who**", "**those students who**" or "**students who**" and none of them will be a mistake. Look at these examples:

- We have many **students** in our class. Those who come from rich families have better books and clothes. *('**Those**' refers to '**students**')*

if you change "**those who**" to "**those students who**" or "**students who**" you simply repeat the *particular noun* again. The word "**those**" already substitutes for "**students**".

"those [noun]" is really okay if you are going to speak about a different particular noun or you're including something within the original substitution:

- We have many **students** in our class. Those of us who come from rich families have better books and clothes. *(Here you mention that you too are with the students who are rich.)*

Comment: In addition, changing it would limit participants to only students (by implication) instead of allowing teachers/staff/parents to participate. That may not be an intentional limitation.